# Delete duplicated records within row in a df in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I would like to get rid of duplicated records in each row of my df:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,3,5), b =c(1,2,4), c=c(2,3,7))

  X1 X2 X3
1  1  1  2
2  3  2  3
3  5  4  7
```

I want to get this:

```
  X1 X2 X3
1  1 NA  2
2  3  2 NA
3  5  4  7
```

Now, I can achieve this using `apply`:

```
data.frame(t(apply(df,1, function(row) ifelse(!duplicated(row), row, NA))))
```

but it seems unlikely that there isn't a more compact (and perhaps efficient) way of achieving this.

Am I missing a command or package here?

Comment: Your function is pretty compact as is.  I'd use pipes to make it a little clearer to read, but it serves your purpose well.

Comment: I don't think so.  If you want to replace the original data frame, then `df[t(apply(df,1,duplicated))]<-NA` is slightly more compact.

Comment: I think that your line could be improved by `df[t(apply(df,1,duplicated))]<-NA`. Also, don't use `data.frame`s; your object is better suited for a `matrix`.

Comment: yes, that looks better, thanks. mrip beat you by 20 sec, nicola.